# Matrix-valued periodic Fibonacci polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, polynomials

Consider the Fibonacci polynomials $f_n(x)$, defined by the recursion $f_n(x)=xf_{n-1}(x)-f_{n-2}(x)$ with initial values $f_0(x)=0$ and $f_1(x)=1$. It is well known that the values of these polynomials 
 are periodic with period $6$ for $x=1$ and $x=-1.$

There are also some matrices $x$ with integer coefficients for which the sequence $f_n(x)$ is periodic.

For example let $$x=g_k=\left(g(i,j)\right)_{i,j=0}^{k-1}$$ be the matrix with entries $g(i,j)=1$ if $|i-j|=1$ or $i=j=0$ and $g(i,j)=0$ else.

Then the sequence $f_n(x)$ is periodic with period $2(2k+1).$

Let for example $k=2$. Here we get a sequence with period $10:$

$\left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} -1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 &-1
 \end{matrix} \right )$, $\left ( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right )$
,$\dots$.

There are also some other matrices $x$ with integer coefficients such that the sequence $f_n(x)$ is periodic. I would be interested to find all such matrices with integer coefficients. Is there anything in the literature?

Comment: We seem to have $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \binom{n-1-k}{k} (-1)^k x^{n-2k-1}$

Answer (score 3):

Up to a change of basis, we can assume the matrix is in Jordan form $M = \bigoplus J_i$. It is known that for every polynomial $p$ one has

## $$
p(J_i) = 
p(\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 1\\
& \lambda & 1\\
& & \ddots & \ddots\\
& & & \lambda & 1\\
& & & & \lambda\\
\end{bmatrix})
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p(\lambda) & p'(\lambda) & \frac{p''(\lambda)}{2} & \dots & \frac{p^{(n-1)}(\lambda)}{n!}\\
& p(\lambda) & p'(\lambda) & \dots & \frac{p^{(n-2)}(\lambda)}{(n-1)!}\\
& & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\
& & & p(\lambda) & p'(\lambda)\\
&&&&p(\lambda)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In particular, periodicity depends on periodicity of the sequence on the eigenvalues of the matrix, and on the sequence of derivatives in case there are nontrivial Jordan blocks.

So if the matrix is diagonalizable, its period is the lcm of all periods of the eigenvalues. If it has Jordan blocks, you have to work out periods of derivatives of the sequence as well.

So you can reduce your problem to a scalar one. Have you solved that completely? Do you know if there are other periodic values other than $\pm 1$ ?

Comment: @ Federico Poloni: If I already have an integer valued matrix as in the special case $k=2$ where the matrix has two different eigenvalues which satisfy $a^2=a+1$, then it reduces  to the sequence $f_n(a).$ This is a one-dimensional case, but with non-integer $a$ . In this case it is easy to verify that it is periodic with period $10$. But the problem is to find such matrices with integer coefficients.

Comment: OK, I see. I read the first revision and it did not mention the fact that the entries must be integers. I am deleting this answer soon as it does not answer the revised question anymore.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think you could maybe update the answer instead. See, suppose we are given some matrix $A$ with a cyclic vector (1 Jordan block is a special case). Then, consider our vector space as $\mathbb{C}[x]$ module (multiplication by $x$ acts by $A$), it is identified with $\mathbb{C}[x]/P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is a minimal polynomial of $A$.

Now, if we take $P(x) = gcd(f_n(x), f_{n+1}(x)-1)$, then multiplication by $x$ satisfies the desired periodicity (and universal in a sense that any other matrix of period $n$ has the same or lesser Jordan blocks with the same eigenvalues).

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't exactly give the full classification (because what is this gcd and when it is nontrivial is not clear), but we could probably work it out quite easily.

Comment: @LevSoukhanov The details are not fully clear to me but it looks promising -- you should write it up as an answer yourself!

Comment: Also, the scalar problem should be easy, right? You have $S = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & x\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and want to know when it is periodic. It is more or less clear: it has determinant one and so only requirement is that its trace equals $2\cos(\frac{2\pi p}{q})$. It closes the scalar problem. I believe there shouldn't be any non-trivial Jordan blocks in the matrix version of the problem (but didn't do it yet).